# Why ZFS file system is not shared after boot?

Tags: nfs, network-share, zfs

I turn on `sharenfs` for ZFS file system, but after reboot it is not shared. And I need to turn file system share again.

Here how it looks:

```
user@ht ~ $ sudo zfs get sharenfs
NAME          PROPERTY  VALUE     SOURCE
family        sharenfs  off       local
family/album  sharenfs  on        local
```

As you can see `sharenfs` is `on`. But file system is not shared:

```
user@ht ~ $ showmount -e 
Export list for ht:
user@ht ~ $
```

When I set `sharenfs` again. File system is shared and I can mount it:

```
user@ht ~ $ sudo zfs set sharenfs=on family/album
user@ht ~ $ showmount -e 
Export list for ht:
/media/user/family/album *
```

**UPD**

My system is `Linux Mint 18.0`

```
$ uname -a
Linux kes-desktop 4.8.0-30-generic #32~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 03:43:51 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**UPD2**

I expect it is shared automatically according to [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gamnd/index.html)

> ZFS can automatically share file systems by setting the sharenfs property.

**UPD3**

```
$ cat /etc/default/zfs
ht default # cat zfs
ZFS_AUTOIMPORT_TIMEOUT='30'
ZFS_SHARE='no'
ZFS_UNSHARE='no'
ZFS_DKMS_ENABLE_DEBUG='no'
ZFS_DKMS_ENABLE_DEBUG_DMU_TX='no'
ZFS_DKMS_DISABLE_STRIP='no'
```

Comment: Do you have the `/etc/default/zfs` file? If not, best would be to [read this post](https://pthree.org/2012/12/31/zfs-administration-part-xv-iscsi-nfs-and-samba/).

Comment: If you installed `zfs` form the Ubuntu repositories, there is a file `/etc/default/zfs` and by default `ZFS_SHARE='no'` and `ZFS_UNSHARE='no'` is disabled which does not automatically export your pool, no matter if you have set `sharenfs` or not on your pool. So, it would be helpful to know the settings you have in that file.

Comment: @Thomas In my file those settings are `no`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the following options in `/etc/default/zfs`.

```
ZFS_SHARE='yes'
ZFS_UNSHARE='yes'
```

This will start the NFS exports of zfs pools which additionally have the `sharenfs` set to `on` or valid NFS export options.

I also would recommend to read [this documention](https://pthree.org/2012/12/31/zfs-administration-part-xv-iscsi-nfs-and-samba/).